# Spaces in file name (not path) in ProcessStartInfo C#

Tags: c#, command-line, ffmpeg

I am running ffmpeg using C# 's ProcessStartInfo where I have to convert the files from one format to another.Those files having no spaces in them is working fine but those having spaces are getting stuck at the error.I think this is due to the spaces in the file name.
e.g

```
  startInfo.Arguments = "-i " + filename+ ".mov-q:a 0 -map a " + filename+ ".mp4";
```

filename is derived at the run time by parsing the directory .
typical error prone filename e.g is = "this is my file"

How can this be resolved.

Comment: use quote, see this : "d:\this is a file.mp4"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enclose the filename in quotation marks:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "-i \"" + filename+ ".mov\" -q:a 0 -map a \"" +
                      filename + ".mp4\"";
```

In C# quotation marks inside strings are escaped either using a backslash (`"\""`) or in verbatim strings via double quotation marks (`s = @"text ""quoted"" ..."`).

---

Consider using verbatim strings and C# 6 string interpolation:

```
startInfo.Arguments = $@"-i ""{filename}.mov"" -q:a 0 -map a ""{filename}.mp4""";
```

which I think is more readable (but that maybe a matter of taste).